# Entity Framework Core How to Improve Query Speed

Tags: performance, linq, timezone, entity-framework-core

So I'm still fairly new using Entity Framework Core, but have recently run into some performance issues related to a few functions I have. I'm wondering what are some obvious steps I can take to improve performance.

```
public int GetMilesTraveled(int userId)
{
    var bookings = new BookingRepository().GetList(p => p.OwnerId == userId &&
                                                   TimeProvider.Current.UtcNow > GetArrivalTimeInUTC(p),
                                                   p => p.Route);
    return bookings.Sum(p => p.Route.Distance);
}

public DateTime GetArrivalTimeInUTC(Booking booking)
{
    var airport = new AirportRepository().GetSingle(p => p.Id == booking.Route.ArrivalAirportId);

    return GetTimeZoneInUTC(airport.Timezone,
                            new DateTime(booking.FlightDate.Date.Ticks + booking.Route.ArrivalTime.Ticks));
}

public DateTime GetTimeZoneInUTC(string timeZoneId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(
            TZConvert.IanaToWindows(timeZoneId));

    var UTC_Time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(
            DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime,
                                 DateTimeKind.Unspecified),
                                 timeZone);

    return UTC_Time;
}
```

At the moment its taking upwards of **2 seconds** for my `GetMilesTraveled(...)` function to return the result of about 32 rows. This is unsustainable for me because the worst case scenario would be a result with about **500** rows.

I believe the `GetArrivalTimeInUTC(...)` function is the current bottleneck, but I'm not sure how it can be improved since I want to store the time zone information as an IANA time zone so I won't have to deal with daylight-savings-time related instances (I believe thats how it'll work).

As for not including `Airport` as a navigation property in the original query, my Repository interface doesn't have an easy way to do `ThenInclude(...)` type operations introduced in .NetCore, and I haven't figured out how to incorporate that.

Are there any obvious performance enhancements I can make to easily speed this up?

Comment: *I believe the GetArrivalTimeInUTC(...) function is the current bottleneck* - don't *believe* - **measure!**

Comment: `TimeProvider.Current.UtcNow > GetArrivalTimeInUTC(p)` cannot be translated to SQL. This results in a query only filtering by `OwnerId`. The time condition will be performed locally calling `GetArrivalTimeInUTC` for each booking, meaning that a `AirportRepository` query will be performed for each one of them. Convert the `TimeProvider.Current.UtcNow` to the database date format before executing the query and don't call local functions in the query. Do you have a good reason for not adding the airport navigation property?

Comment: If you show the signature of your repository `GetList` method, we could eventually figure out something.

Comment: In the first sight of your query, I see too much round trip to the database because of GetArrivalTimeInUTC method because this method cannot perform in the databse so EF should return all your Booking record and after that compare each record. All in all, you should revise your query.